# Convert google product taxonomy to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there an easy way to convert the google product taxonomy list to a multidimensional array?

http://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy.en-GB.txt

So far i have

```
    $taxonomy = file_get_contents('assets/taxonomy.en-GB.txt');
    $taxonomy = explode("\n", $taxonomy);
    array_shift($taxonomy);
```

but this just puts it into a flat array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('taxonomy.data');
$file = explode("\n", $file);
$taxonomy = array();
foreach ($file as $index => $line) {
    $fields = explode(" > ", $line);
    $cursor = &$taxonomy;
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($cursor[$field])) {
            $cursor[$field] = array();
        }
        $cursor = &$cursor[$field];
    }
}

print_r($taxonomy);
?>
```

Comment: print_r($taxonomy) doesn't print it in php array format. To convert the output into usable php array  :  echo "<pre>"; var_export($taxonomy); echo "</pre>";